# How to Parse this JSON in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

How to Parse this JSON in Codeigniter (It is a response of ajax)

```
   {"status":true,"data":{"order_detail":[{"id":"1","order_number":"123","customer_name":"Ramm","amount":"","delivery_date":"2017-09-29","order_status":"Out for Delivery","discount":"100","total_cloth":"","mobile":"1223323344","customer_address":"delhii","store_id":"1","payment_mode":"Cash","payment_status":"Paid"}],"cloth_detail":[{"id":"55","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Men-Jeans ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"37","treatment":"DryCleaning "},{"id":"56","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Men-Jeans ","cloth_color":"Blue ","quantity":"232","treatment":"DryCleaning "},{"id":"57","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Shirt ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"560","treatment":"Washing "},{"id":"58","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Shirt ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"423","treatment":"Washing + Pressing "},{"id":"59","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Pant ","cloth_color":"Blue ","quantity":"5435","treatment":"DryCleaning "}]}}
```

Comment: This "question" does not contain a question. What would you like to ask us?

Comment: use `json_decode`

Comment: Neha Can You Update your Question with Your Question !! So We know the issue :)

Comment: You Can use `json_decode()`

Comment: @Neha Sharma : **(It is a response of ajax)** you want to parse on frontend using js or backend using php ? Please make it clear

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.parse inbuilt function.

```
var x = '{"status":true,"data":{"order_detail":[{"id":"1","order_number":"123","customer_name":"Ramm","amount":"","delivery_date":"2017-09-29","order_status":"Out for Delivery","discount":"100","total_cloth":"","mobile":"1223323344","customer_address":"delhii","store_id":"1","payment_mode":"Cash","payment_status":"Paid"}],"cloth_detail":[{"id":"55","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Men-Jeans ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"37","treatment":"DryCleaning "},{"id":"56","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Men-Jeans ","cloth_color":"Blue ","quantity":"232","treatment":"DryCleaning "},{"id":"57","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Shirt ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"560","treatment":"Washing "},{"id":"58","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Shirt ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"423","treatment":"Washing + Pressing "},{"id":"59","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Pant ","cloth_color":"Blue ","quantity":"5435","treatment":"DryCleaning "}]}}';
```

Then you can parse

```
var myjson = JSON.parse(x);
```

Then you get an object from JSON.parse

```
var status = myjson.status // you get true as per your json object
```

For Order Detail

```
var orderDetail = myjson.data.order_detail;
```

I hope this helps you .

Comment: and what about order_detail how to fetch all other rest? can you give me some hint

Comment: You can get order details also easily
`var orderdetail = myjson.data.order_detail;`

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can parse `json` value by using

```
/* **data** is response you recieved by ajax*/
  var json =  JSON.parse(data);
```

if u want to fetch `status` data

```
 var status = json.status;
```

```js
var data =' {"status":true,"data":{"order_detail":[{"id":"1","order_number":"123","customer_name":"Ramm","amount":"","delivery_date":"2017-09-29","order_status":"Out for Delivery","discount":"100","total_cloth":"","mobile":"1223323344","customer_address":"delhii","store_id":"1","payment_mode":"Cash","payment_status":"Paid"}],"cloth_detail":[{"id":"55","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Men-Jeans ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"37","treatment":"DryCleaning "},{"id":"56","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Men-Jeans ","cloth_color":"Blue ","quantity":"232","treatment":"DryCleaning "},{"id":"57","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Shirt ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"560","treatment":"Washing "},{"id":"58","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Shirt ","cloth_color":"Red ","quantity":"423","treatment":"Washing + Pressing "},{"id":"59","order_no":"123","cloth_type":"Pant ","cloth_color":"Blue ","quantity":"5435","treatment":"DryCleaning "}]}}';
var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
/*console.log(json_data);*/

var status =  json_data.status;
console.log(status);
var order_det = json_data.data;
for (var k in order_det) {
  console.log(order_det[k]);
  /* if u want to get id */
  console.log(order_det[k][0].id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> You Can Do This Using JavaScript **`JSON.parse`**

```
var myArray_Var = JSON.parse(YourJSONString);
```